# calling other class by hiera not working in rspec-puppet

Tags: rspec, puppet

I am facing an issue when use rspec-puppet for hiera_hash

Below is the first example

```
class users {

  include users::example1
  }

class users::example1 {

 $abc = {
    'example1' => {
      'ensure'   => 'present',
      'shell'    => '/usr/bin/ksh',
      'home'     => '/home/example1',
      password'  => 'xxxxxxxx',
      'mode'     => '0700',
    }
  }
  create_resources('users::example1',$abc)
}
```

I wrote rspec for this, please find it below

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'users', :type => 'class' do

  it { should contain_class('users::example1')}
end
```

It is working without any issue

Below is the second example

```
class env {
      include env::filetype
    }

class env::filetype {

  $tmp = hiera_hash('env::abc')
  create_resources('logical::myfile, $tmp)
}
```

I am getting below error when I run the manifests

```
Failures:

  1) env should contain Class[env::filetype]
     Failure/Error: it { should contain_class('env::filetype')}
     Puppet::Error:
       Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type logical::myfile at /etc//puppet/modules/env/spec/fixtures/modules/env/manifests/filetype.pp:7 on node 
     # ./spec/classes/env_spec.rb:5

Finished in 0.20231 secondsI 1 example, 1 failure
```

So, my doubt is the rspec-puppet test case hiera will work ony inside the same module, If we invoke any other class to pass data in hiera then it wont support in rspec-puppet.

if it is so, How we can achive that is rspec-puppet

Comment: Could you also provide your hiera data files ? Are you sure that hiera_hash returns proper value ? You have also an error in example code, "`" is missing, should be create_resources('logical::myfile', $tmp)

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite specific:

```
ArgumentError: Invalid resource type logical::myfile at /etc//puppet/modules/env/spec/fixtures/modules/env/manifests/filetype.pp:7
```

This probably means that the `logical` module is not available to `rspec-puppet`. Make sure that the module is part of the test suite's fixtures.